# Why does the dotTrace profiler cause my AspDotNetStorefront website to throw a server error?

Tags: asp.net, profiling, strongname, dottrace, aspdotnetstorefront

Our company has an ASP.NET ecommerce site based on AspDotNetStorefront which has been in production for about six months.  We are trying to profile it with dotTrace on my development machine.  dotTrace causes .NET to throw an error when loading the default page.  The error is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'AspDotNetStorefrontCore,
>   Version=9.0.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies.  A strongly-named assembly is required.  (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131044)

I've taken two routes to try to fix the error, neither of which worked:

1) I rebuilt the site, signing each Storefront dll with a strong name.

2) I used the sn utility to register the dlls so the CLR would skip strong name validation.

I have also tried to use the Fusion Assembly Binding Log Viewer to look for clues.  Nothing was apparent in the logs.

In addition, I have let dotTrace run the application both as a WebDev app and as an IIS app.  I get the same results either way.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!